# Strange Google Chrome Bug. jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jscrollpane

I have used in my site jScrollPane jquery plugin.
It is normally work in all browsers except Chrome.
Take a look here: http://evarivas.com/bio
In my Chrome I have no problems. Scroll works normally. On another computers sometimes works sometimes doesn't. After refresh works, or doesn't work...

What is this? Very strange...

Comment: +1 because I fear you won't get any answers. jQuery+jScrollPane+Chrome add up to an *incredibly* complex combination of code in several different languages, which makes tracing a "half-the-time" bug almost impossible.

Comment: Form me, Chrome 5.0.375.125 on OS X, it seems to initialize and work properly on every page load... but I found what appears to be a reliable, 100% reproducible way to make this jScrollPane break. The scrolling functions stop working immediately after I use the mousewheel while over the scrollable content.

Comment: Seconded. Chrome 6 on XP here. As soon as I touch the mouse wheel, kaboom.

Comment: On other computers sometimes works...  what browser is breaking for you?  Please give us more information.

Comment: Already upgraded to new version of jScrollPane. Looks like is normally working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been receiving the jScrollPane Google Group messages recently, and I've seen at least two or three people have their issues disappear by placing scripts in the `head` instead of the bottom of the `body`. I realize some performance recommendations suggest scripts at the bottom but in my experience it's not really a significant enough perf gain to justify the often-greater delays in initializing behaviors.

Might be worth a try.

Edit: Just noticed you're using a pretty old version of jScrollPane -- I highly recommend upgrading to build 93 of jScrollPane, which is available by downloading the latest from the google code repository: http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/source/checkout

Simply upgrading may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the entire JScroll library or merely placed a link in the header script?

I had the issue of not being able to get my infinite scroll working on Chrome only, however I realised that this is because Chrome did not recognise the MIME type of my script.

For example, I had:

```
<script src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/master/jquery.jscroll.min.js></script>
```

The correct way of entering a raw script from Github is:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/master/jquery.jscroll.min.js"></script>
```